# mongo object id is not generating inside object of array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs

I am using nestJs for the backend and I have a schema that has an array as an attribute. I need an object id for each array attribute for some purpose but ids are not generating.

DTO for object inside array:

```
export class EmergencyContact {
 @Prop({ _id: true })
 _id: string;

 @Prop()
 @ApiProperty()
 @IsNotEmpty()
 title: string;

 @Prop()
 @ApiProperty()
 @IsNotEmpty()
 contactNumber: string;

 @Prop()
 status: boolean;
}
```

Schema DTO:

```
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class EDiary {
  _id: string;

  @Prop()
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  state: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @Prop()
  @Type(() => EmergencyContact)
  emergencyContact: EmergencyContact[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After research on the internet, I found one solution to the above issue. To get the MongoDB object id inside I did the following changes to my DTO.

```
export class EmergencyContact {
 @Prop()
 _id: string;

 @Prop()
 @ApiProperty()
 @IsNotEmpty()
 title: string;

 @Prop()
 @ApiProperty()
 @IsNotEmpty()
 contactNumber: string;

 @Prop()
 status: boolean;
}


@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class EDiary {
  _id: string;

  @Prop()
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  state: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @ApiProperty()
  @Prop([{
    title: {
      type: String
    },
    contactNumber: {
      type: String
    }, status: {
      type: Boolean
    }
  }])
  @Type(() => EmergencyContact)
  emergencyContact: EmergencyContact[];
}
```